# Techtalk.Specrun.PendingTestException: No matching step definition found for one or more steps

Tags: specflow, specrun

When using Spec Flow and running a feature file that has implemented code behind it, I am seeing this:

> Techtalk.Specrun.PendingTestException: No matching step definition found for     one or more steps

I have code behind each of the features and regardless of what I try I keep getting a pending output.

e.g.

```
Given I browse to Url "http;//www.google.co.uk"
-> No matching step found for the step definition
[Given(@"I browse to Url""(.*)""")]
Public void GivenIBrowseToUrl(String p0)
{
  ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

However the code I have implemented for this feature is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace UserJourney
{
[Binding]
  public class PhoneJourneySteps
  {
    [Given(@"I browser to Url ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenIBrowserToUrl(string url)
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your question?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, as the error message tells you, that you do not have a step with the correct binding.

your step has the binding:

```
[Given(@"I browser to Url ""(.*)""")]
```

it is asking for the binding:

```
[Given(@"I browse to Url""(.*)""")]
```

notice the missing space after `Url`?

remove the space from your binding definition and everything should work ok.

Also I would recommend using single quotes in your steps in the scenario files, it makes the bindings easier to read. So have `Given I browse to the Url'http://google.com/'`